# checking if my input is empty to not take any more values to my list, however I'm struggling to make the check

Tags: python, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop

I trying to take values for my list "age" as long as integers are being inputted. The user is to put a blank line if there are no other inputs left to take. I am trying to write a condition for is the input is empty, to break the while loop.

my code:

```
count = int(0);
age = [input("please enter your age")];
while True:
if age:
    age.append((input("please enter your age")));
else:
    break;
print(age)
```

thank you!

Comment: age is always going to be a non-empty list (truthy), you should check the input before adding it to the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the solutions:

- Use Error handling

```
age = [int(input("please enter your age"))]
while True:        
    try:
        age.append(int(input("please enter your age")));
    except:
        break
print(age)
```

```
OR
```

- Use isnumeric() function

```
age = [int(input("please enter your age"))] #Parentheses issue resolved
while(True):        
    age_ = input("please enter your age")
    if age_.isnumeric():
        age.append(int(age_))
    else:
        break
print(age)
```

Answer (score 0):

the count variable is not needed if you have this problem. I solved the problem by inserting the try/except in the loop. In this way you get only numeric values input, if other values are inserted the loop closes.

```
a = []

while True:
  try:
      na = int(input('Please enter your age? '))
      a.append(na)
  except:
    break
```